# Computing the gradient of a batched function using JAX

Tags: machine-learning, jax, flax

I would need to compute the gradient of a batched function using JAX. The following is a minimal example of what I would like to do:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = jnp.expand_dims(jnp.linspace(-1, 1, 20), axis=1)

u = lambda x: jnp.sin(jnp.pi * x)
ux = jax.vmap(jax.grad(u))

plt.plot(x, u(x))
plt.plot(x, ux(x))  # Use vx instead of ux
plt.show()
```

I have tried a variety of ways of making this work using vmap, but I don't seem to be able to get the code to run without removing the batch dimension in the input x. I have seen some workarounds using the Jacobian but this doesn't seem natural as the given is a scalar function of a single variable.

In the end u will be a neural network (implemented in Flax) that I need to differentiate with respect to the input (not the parameters of the network), so I cannot remove the batch dimension.

Comment: What is `vx` in the comment referring to?

Comment: I apologize, this comment can be ignored, it referred to a deleted line when I did some experimentation!

Comment: If you want to use `jax.grad`, you'll need to map over the batched axis too so that `u` returns a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the kernel (`u`) returns a scalar value, so that `jax.grad` makes sense, the batched dimension also needs to be mapped over.

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = jnp.expand_dims(jnp.linspace(-1, 1, 20), axis=1)

u = lambda x: jnp.sin(jnp.pi * x)
ux = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(jax.grad(u)))
# ux = lambda x : jax.lax.map(jax.vmap(jax.grad(u)), x) # sequential version
# ux = lambda x : jax.vmap(jax.grad(u))(x.reshape(-1)).reshape(x.shape) # flattened map version

plt.plot(x, u(x))
plt.plot(x, ux(x))  # Use vx instead of ux
plt.show()
```

Which composition of maps to use depends on what's happening in the batched dimension.

Comment: Great, this solves the issue! If you don't mind, how would this answer have to be modified, if the function u had some extra parameters (the weights of the neural network), but I still want the derivatives w.r.t. the input x?

Comment: If you're not differentiating with respect to the extra arguments, you can either close over them or specify `in_axes` to `jax.vmap` and `argnums` to `jax.grad`. if you post another question specifying the extra parameters, the values for the previous arguments can be defined.

Comment: Many thanks! I think it worked just using your code snippet from before, just adding the parameters and not mapping them using vmap. I appreciate your help here!